# Parquet4s: how to write column names in snake case

Tags: scala, parquet

I'm using [parquet4s](https://mjakubowski84.github.io/parquet4s/) in Scala to write parquet files.
The column names in the output parquet file are in LowerCamelCase (the same as they are defined in the case class).
I'm wondering how can I convert them to snake_case.

Example code:

```
import com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.{ ParquetReader, ParquetWriter, Path }

case class NestedClass(
    myId: Int,
    myOther: String
)

case class MyDataModel(
    myId: Long,
    myNestedClass: NestedClass
)

val record = MyDataModel(myId = 1L, myNestedClass = NestedClass(myId=2, myOther="sth"))
val path = Path("<my_path>/file.parquet")

// writing
ParquetWriter.of[MyDataModel].writeAndClose(path, List(record))
```

Parquet schema in output:

```
message MyDataModel {
  required int64 myId (INTEGER(64,true));
  optional group myNestedClass {
    required int32 myId (INTEGER(32,true));
    optional binary myOther (STRING);
  }
}
```

My goal is to transform the column names to snake case, like `my_id`, `my_nested_class`, etc

EDIT:
I found a solution, but it's not a sustainable one, because it involves redefining each field (name and type).
The solution would be to add an implicit schema and value encoder for each case class. Example:

```
given nestedClassCodec: OptionalValueEncoder[NestedClass] =
  (data: NestedClass, _: ValueCodecConfiguration) => RowParquetRecord(
    ("my_id", IntValue(data.myId)),
    ("my_other", BinaryValue(data.myOther))
  )

given nestedClassSchema: TypedSchemaDef[NestedClass] =
  SchemaDef.group(
    Types.primitive(INT32, REQUIRED).as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.intType(32, true)).named("my_id"),
    Types.primitive(BINARY, OPTIONAL).as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.stringType()).named("my_other"),
  ).typed[NestedClass]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the issue?

Comment: @GaëlJ , I edited my post and added a "solution/workaround" I found yesterday. It's not a good solution, but I think it gives an idea of what's needed

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to create a custom ParquetSchemaResolver and a  ParquetRecordEncoder for my case class.

Below is the implementation.

If you use it, check if all your data types are implemented.
I haven't implemented the encoder for all of them (e.g. the `MapParquetRecord`) because I didn't need it.

```
import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat
import org.apache.parquet.schema.{ GroupType, LogicalTypeAnnotation, PrimitiveType, Type, Types }
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.*

def camelToSnake(name: String): String = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, name)

implicit val schemaResolver: ParquetSchemaResolver[MyDataModel] =
  new ParquetSchemaResolver.derived[MyDataModel] {

    def camelToSnakeField(t: Type): Type = t match {
      case g: GroupType =>
        Types
          .buildGroup(g.getRepetition)
          .as(g.getLogicalTypeAnnotation)
          .named(camelToSnake(g.getName))
          .withNewFields(g.getFields.asScala.map(camelToSnakeField).asJava)
      case p: PrimitiveType =>
        Types
          .primitive(p.getPrimitiveTypeName, p.getRepetition)
          .as(p.getLogicalTypeAnnotation)
          .named(camelToSnake(p.getName))
      case _ => throw NotImplementedError(s"Schema resolver not implemented for type ${t.toString}")
    }

    override def resolveSchema(cursor: Cursor): List[Type] = {
      super.resolveSchema(cursor).map(camelToSnakeField)
    }
  }

implicit val recordEncoder: ParquetRecordEncoder[MyDataModel] =
  new ParquetRecordEncoder.derived[MyDataModel] {

    def camelToSnakeValue(v: Value): Value = v match {
      case r: RowParquetRecord  => RowParquetRecord(r.iterator.toList.map(camelToSnakeField))
      case l: ListParquetRecord => ListParquetRecord(l.iterator.toList.map(camelToSnakeValue)*)
      case v                    => v
    }

    def camelToSnakeField(field: (String, Value)): (String, Value) = field match {
      case (name: String, v: PrimitiveValue[?]) => (camelToSnake(name), v)
      case (name: String, l: ListParquetRecord) =>
        (camelToSnake(name), ListParquetRecord(l.iterator.toList.map(camelToSnakeValue)*))
      case (name: String, r: RowParquetRecord) =>
        (camelToSnake(name), RowParquetRecord(r.iterator.toList.map(camelToSnakeField)))
      case (name: String, NullValue) => (camelToSnake(name), NullValue)
      case (name: String, any) =>
        throw NotImplementedError(s"Encoder not implemented for field $name with type ${any.toString}")
    }

    override def encode(
                         entity: MyDataModel,
                         resolver: EmptyRowParquetRecordResolver,
                         configuration: ValueCodecConfiguration
                       ): RowParquetRecord =
      val fields: Iterator[(String, Value)] = super.encode(entity, resolver, ValueCodecConfiguration.Default).iterator
      val newFields                         = fields.toList.map(camelToSnakeField)
      RowParquetRecord(newFields*)
  }
```